# How to force local minimums plotting under graph in adjust_text?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got  this graph:

```
# graph plot
plt.plot(
    df_for_pred['date'],
    df_for_pred['mentee_per_mentor'],
    color="r"
)
plt.title('Mentee per mentor dynamic')
plt.grid(False)

# graph_annotates contains local highs and lows
labels = [plt.text(graph_annotates['date'][i], graph_annotates['mentee_per_mentor'][i],
                   f"{graph_annotates['mentee_per_mentor'][i]:.2f}") for i in graph_annotates.index]

adjust_text(labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

How to force lows to be under graph (hight - under graph)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried as I don't have similar data so my code might need little adjustments. But the idea is to compare to the next value, and if next > current, decrease the y-coord by a little amount.
Of course you won't be able to do it for the last value that you'll have to label separately as there are no next value.

```py
y_s = [graph_annotates['mentee_per_mentor'][i] - 0.1 
       if (graph_annotates['mentee_per_mentor'][i + 1] > graph_annotates['mentee_per_mentor'][i]) 
       else graph_annotates['mentee_per_mentor'][i] 
       for i in graph_annotates.index[:-1]]

labels = [plt.text(graph_annotates['date'][i], y_s[i],
                   f"{graph_annotates['mentee_per_mentor'][i]:.2f}")
          for i in graph_annotates.index[:-1]]
```

Comment: Thanks! But I make it a bit different way. When I make list with local highs/lows I multiply values on 1 (high) or 0.98 (low).